# How can I use Nexus repository in other microservice projects?

Tags: java, spring, jenkins, nexus, nexus3

I created a repository on Nexus with Jenkins pipeline. I created the spring boot jar inside. Now I want to access this repository from another microservice project. I added some configurations to the settings.xml file under the ~/.m2 directory. And What should I add to the pom.xml file to access the repository?
[image: settings.xml]